# Write a function in JavaScript which accept three numbers as arguments and display the greatest number

Tags: javascript

I tried it using making an array first and then choosing max out of it but the output is always `NaN`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Write a function in JavaScript which accept three numbers as arguments and
 display the greatest number.</h2>



<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


selnum = [num1, num2, num3];

var num1 = prompt("Please wirte any number");
var num2 = prompt ("Please write 2nd number");
var num3 = prompt("Please wirte 3rd number");

document.write(Math.max(selnum));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `selnum = [num1, num2, num3];` has to be *after* you assign the 3 variables.

Comment: Was Window.prompt() your idea or part of the assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions.

You can do it with an Array, or with only var.

With array:

```js
var num1 = prompt("Please write any number");
var num2 = prompt("Please write 2nd number");
var num3 = prompt("Please write 3rd number");

var arr = [num1, num2, num3];

document.write(Math.max(...arr));
```

With var:

```js
var num1 = prompt("Please write any number");
var num2 = prompt("Please write 2nd number");
var num3 = prompt("Please write 3rd number");

document.write(Math.max(num1, num2, num3));
```

If you don't want to you Math.max you can do:

```js
var num1 = prompt("Please write any number");
var num2 = prompt("Please write 2nd number");
var num3 = prompt("Please write 3rd number");

var arr = [num1, num2, num3];

var maxi = num1;

for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    maxi = (maxi < arr[i] ? arr[i] : maxi);
}

document.write(maxi);
```

With a function it will look something like:

```js
function f(num1, num2, num3){
   return Math.max(num1, num2, num3); // Without array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `selnum = [num1, num2, num3];` is happening *before* you actually get the numbers from the user.  You need to put that line *after* the `prompt()` lines.

You may also need to convert the values to numbers, as `prompt()` always returns a string and these may not sort the way you expect.

Finally, `Math.max` doesn't accept an array, it accepts an unlimited number of parameters.  So you need to use `.apply` here.

```js
var num1 = prompt("Please wirte any number");
var num2 = prompt("Please write 2nd number");
var num3 = prompt("Please wirte 3rd number");
    
var selnum = [parseInt(num1, 10), parseInt(num2, 10), parseInt(num3, 10)];
    
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, selnum));
```

Also, `document.write` really isn't used anymore.  Use `console.log` and check your developer console in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Found this as the working one

```
<script>

var num1 = prompt("Please wirte any number");
var num2 = prompt("Please write 2nd number");
var num3 = prompt("Please wirte 3rd number");




document.write(Math.max(num1, num2, num3));


</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

`Math.max()` doesn't take an array as an argument, it requires each value to be a separate argument.

You also have to convert the inputs to numbers.

```js
var num1 = +prompt("Please wirte any number");
var num2 = +prompt("Please write 2nd number");
var num3 = +prompt("Please wirte 3rd number");

getMax(num1, num2, num3);

function getMax(num1, num2, num3) {
  console.log(Math.max(num1, num2, num3));
}
```

Comment: "write a function".... am I missing something?